# Was Dumbledore related to any characters mentioned in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore, genealogy

There were a lot of family connections between everyone and everyone in HP... Harry and Ignotus, Voldemort and Slytherin, the Blacks and everyone else (Tonks, Weasleys, etc...)

Was there any info (canon or JKR) that Dumbledore was related to anyone? He lived in Godric's Hollow, but that is not necessarily a basis for any leaps of logic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Dumbledore was related to his immediate family: His father, who was sentenced to life in Azkaban for killing the three Muggles who attacked Dumbledore's younger sister Ariana. Aberforth Dumbledore is Albus's brother, and he runs the Hog's Head inn in Hogsmeade. Dumbledore's mother, Kendra, was accidentally killed by Ariana, during one of her out-of-control fits. The family was not originally from Godric's Hollow, so I don't think there's a significance to Dumbledore, Godric's Hollow, and Godric Gryffindor. Because Dumbledore has red hair and blue eyes, there have been a thousand theories that Dumbledore is a Weasley, particularly Ron. JKR has debunked all these rumours. There is nothing in canon that identifies further individuals as being related to Dumbledore except the following.

Dumbledore also has a "maiden aunt" Honoria, who called off her engagement to a wizard in the Improper Use of Magic Office because she discovered "he had a hairy heart". It was rumoured, however, that she actually discovered him in the act of fondling some Horklumps, which she found deeply shocking (*Tales of Beetle the Bard* - page 106 - Collector's Edition).

Comment: " JKR has debunked all these rumours." - what, no quote? hell just froze over :)

Comment: "fondling some Horklumps" - that just sound like a REALLY bad fanfic :)

Comment: @DVK I'm distracted by fonts fOnTs FONTS! Re: Horklumps, IKR? *Harry Potter and the Traumatised Horklumps* . . . (I suppose you want me to dig up that quote, don't you? ;) )

Comment: No quote, no love... err... accept.

Comment: But. . . what about the Horklumps. . . ?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't touch them at all, why are you asking **me**?

Comment: Fine, I will stop talking about Horklumps. :)

Comment: It's like listening to my childhood heroes argue. @DVK

Comment: @BorhanMooz - **DVK** and I go way back. We always argue! But, at the end of the day, as the epilogue in *Deathly Hallows* says: *All was well*. :) (BTW, would you like a Horklump?)

Comment: That's good to hear. No thanks, prefer Snorkaks.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Why nuke the link? I think it adds value.

Comment: @TheDarkLord The link was *not* included by the original author of this answer - indeed the link target was only created several years later. Also the link target only mentions one very specific and implausible theory debunked by JKR, not giving any evidence against the other claims, so it doesn't actually say what the link text suggests. Better to leave the answer in Sly's original form unless she wants to change it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor She seems to be referring specifically to the theory that Dumbledore is Ron. "...there have been a thousand theories that Dumbledore is a Weasley, particularly Ron." I think it's useful personally to see where she addressed that specific point.

Comment: @TheDarkLord "JKR has debunked all these rumours" but the link only debunks one of them. Feel free to drop a link in comments, but I don't think it's good to edit it into someone else's post in that way.

Answer (score 0):

Might Dumbledore be related to Harry, as in Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald Dumbledore says that a phoenix will go to any Dumbledore in need, and Fawkes went to Harry's side in the Chamber of Secrets.

Comment: Sent by Dumbledore

Comment: @Valorum still though it's an interesting thought. Has JKR addressed it?

Comment: Repeatedly, I think.

Comment: [Addressed here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63359/76048), though it was closed as a duplicate of this one.