# Were the Potters in any way related with the Dumbledores?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

Is there any canon indication (books, films or any additional materials) that Harry Potter is in any way related to Albus Dumbledore?

There seem to be some similarities between them like

- Ancestors of both were always placed in Gryffindor.
- Both have connections with Godrics Hollow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no mention in the books about Albus Dumbledore's ancestors being placed in Griffindor (or any other house for that matter).
2. The only known connection between Albus Dumbledore and Godrics Hollow is that his family moved there after his father was imprisoned, that he happened to be placed in Gryffindore house when he joined Hogwarts, and Gryffindore was born in Godrics Hollow