# Is Harry Potter part of the Dumbledore family?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

As per *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald*, a Phoenix would come to any Dumbledore who is in trouble/need.

In *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Phoenix arrives to help Harry in the Chamber of Secrets.

Can we conclude that Harry Potter was related to Dumbledore family in some way or the other?

Comment: Now THAT would be a plot twist.

Comment: It's true that Dumbledore didn't send Fawkes to Harry in CoS. Dumbledore says that Fawkes acted of his own accord. He also explains that phoenixes make very loyal pets, so he (Fawkes) went to help Harry because Harry showed Dumbledore that same loyalty. I don't think it was because Harry is a part of the Dumbledore family.

Comment: This is the logical fallacy of [***affirming the consequent***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: Duplicate of [Were the Potters in any way related with the Dumbledores?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/63359/31394), which is in turn a duplicate of [Was Dumbledore related to any characters mentioned in Harry Potter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10304/31394)

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: yes, but statistically, the fact that Fawkes came to help Harry reinforce the credence (!) that he is related to the Dumbledore family.

Comment: @Taladris - No it doesn't: Being a Dumbledore is a _sufficient_ condition for having the help of a phoenix; it is nowhere indicated as a _necessary_ condition. In fact, The Lethal Carrot posted an answer, _with a cite from the book in question_, that suggests that being a Dumbledore _isn't_ a _necessary_ condition, and that _loyalty **to** a Dumbledore_ is _also_ a _sufficient_ condition. I strongly urge you to study a bit more Propositional Calculus/Propositional Logic/Syllogistic Logic, with special attention to propositional/syllogistic fallacies.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin: thanks for the lecture, but you are missing the point. My comment was a (lame?) pun on the word credence. Also, I was speaking about statistics: the probability that someone will have the help of a phoenix (H) knowing that he is a Dumbledore (D) is quite high (close to 1), otherwise it would not be worth mentioning it. Now, the credence that Harry is a Dumbledore after witnessing it has been helped by a phoenix, aka p(D|H), is reinforced by the observation, that is P(D|H) > p(D). You should look up at (Bayesian) statistics and the Dunning-Kruger effect...

Answer (score 5):

It is very unlikely and if so Harry would be very distantly related to the Dumbledores. In fact, whilst we know little of the Dumbledore family, we have quite an extensive history of the Potter family and the Potter family tree, per the [*Harry Potter* wikia](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Potter_family) (sorry!), doesn't mention the Dumbledores.

[image: Potter family tree]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

In fact there is no mention that I can find of the Potters and Dumbledores being related. Though, as we know, all of the pure-blood families are pretty much related in one way or the other.

However, it would seem your reasoning for thinking Harry is related to the Dumbledores is incorrect. Dumbledore himself has an answer for why Fawkes came to Harry in the Chamber.

> “First of all, Harry, I want to thank you,” said Dumbledore, eyes twinkling again. “You must have shown me real loyalty down in the Chamber. Nothing but that could have called Fawkes to you.”
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, Chapter 18, "Dobby's Reward"</sub>